# error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have been trying to install `ImageMagick` in `Ubuntu 16.04` to use with `movie.py`

I have installed `ImageMagick 7` but when I check the version from the command line

```
convert --version
```

It gives error as

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried running

```
sudo ldconfig /user/local/lib
```

But, still getting same error.

> Edit 2: How I installed

1. Downloaded two `rpm` files from [imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
2. run following commands to install in Ubuntu 16.04

   sudo alien -i ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-37.x86_64.rpm
   sudo alien -i ImageMagick-7.0.7-37.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Please show **how** you installed it, since that appears to be the problem.

Comment: updated steps followed to install

Answer (score 46):

You may need to run this: `ldconfig /usr/local/lib`

Comment: I guess this is what question poster tried to run, but according to his original question post, he made a typo (`user` instead of `usr`)

Answer (score 6):

Found that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable isn't being created by the installation of ImageMagick, so when I created it manually (on Linux Mint 19) -

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Then the ImageMagick commands work, without generating the error message -
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Better: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this error when attempting to install ImageMagick 7.0.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 (using WSL on Windows 10).

Running this fixed my problem:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/lib64
```

I found this folder by examining the deb:

```
dpkg -c imagemagick-libs_7.0.10-57_amd64.deb | grep libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.8
```

This showed:

```
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2021-01-09 09:59 ./usr/lib64/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.8 -> libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.8.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you find where the missing library is located:

```
sudo find /usr /opt / -type f -name libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6
```

Then check your `ldconfig` settings match in:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

**Uninstall native version** (if you have installed from tar.gz)

```
cd ImageMagick-7.1.0-19/
sudo make uninstall
```

**Remove apt version**

```
sudo apt remove imagemagick
sudo apt purge imagemagick
```

**Do simple install**

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```